# Check if two linked lists are equal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following implementation of a linked list in Ruby:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next

  def initialize(data = nil)
    @data = data
    @next = nil
  end
end

class LinkedList
  def initialize(items)
    @head = Node.new(items.shift)
    items.inject(@head) { |last, data| @tail = last.next = Node.new(data) }
  end

  def iterate
    return nil if @head.nil?

    entry = @head
    until entry.nil?
      yield entry
      entry = entry.next
    end
  end

  def equal?(other_list)
    #How do I check if all the data for all the elements in one list are the same in the other one?
  end
end
```

I have tried using the .iterate like this:

```
def equals?(other_list)
  other_list.iterate do |ol|
    self.iterate do |sl|
      if ol.data != sl.data
         return false
      end
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

But this is doing a nested approach. I fail to see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it easily with the methods you have defined currently, as there is no way to access a single next element. Also, it would be extremely useful if you implemented `each` instead of `iterate`, which then gives you the whole power of the `Enumerable` mixin.

```
class LinkedList
  include Enumerable  # THIS allows you to use `zip` :)

  class Node # THIS because you didn't give us your Node
    attr_accessor :next, :value
    def initialize(value)
      @value = value
      @next = nil
    end
  end

  def initialize(items)
    @head = Node.new(items.shift)
    items.inject(@head) { |last, data| @tail = last.next = Node.new(data) }
  end

  def each
    return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?  # THIS allows block or blockless calls
    return if @head.nil?

    entry = @head
    until entry.nil?
      yield entry.value  # THIS yields node values instead of nodes
      entry = entry.next
    end
  end

  def ==(other_list)
    # and finally THIS - get pairs from self and other, and make sure all are equal
    zip(other_list).all? { |a, b| a == b }
  end
end

a = LinkedList.new([1, 2, 3])
b = LinkedList.new([1, 2, 3])
c = LinkedList.new([1, 2])

puts a == b  # => true
puts a == c  # => false
```

**EDIT:** I missed this on the first run through: `equal?` is supposed to be referential identity, i.e. two variables are `equal?` if they contain the reference to the same object. You should not redefine that method, even though it is possible. Rather, `==` is the general common-language meaning of "equal" as in "having the same value", so I changed it to that.

Comment: Nice explanation and solution, Amadan. +1. A small point: since you `include Enumerable` you have use of [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a), so I think the method `equal?` can be simplified to `self.to_a == other_list.to_a`. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yes :) However, it would create two new arrays from the original lists. My method does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your initialize method in LinkedList, regardless could this be what you need

`...

    def equal?(other_list)
      other_index = 0
      cur_index = 0
      hash = Hash.new
      other_list.iterate do |ol| 
        hash[ol.data.data] = other_index
        other_index += 1
      end
      self.iterate do |node| 
        return false if hash[node.data.data] != cur_index
        return false if !hash.has_key?(node.data.data) 
        cur_index += 1
      end
      return true
    end
...`

Assuming this is how you use your code

```
a = Node.new(1)
b = Node.new(2)
c = Node.new(3)

listA = [a,b,c]

aa = Node.new(1)
bb = Node.new(2)  
cc = Node.new(3)

listB = [aa,bb,cc]

linkA = LinkedList.new(listA)
linkB = LinkedList.new(listB)

puts linkA.equal?(linkB)
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you think is wrong with my initialize method?